# Batch the test dataset?

Tags: predictive-models, model, accuracy

I have about 1.000.000 samples in total where 70% were for training and the 30% for test.

The training part was done in batches of 100 samples. To test the model, and calculate the accuracy, I can not load all test samples in memory.

Does make sense to use the same idea of training, batch-by-batch, to evaluate the model? If so, an overall accuracy would be the average of batch accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, but this is dependent on the size of your batch dividing the number of testing examples evenly.  A better approach would be to run the model on each testing batch, saving the predictions, and calculate the accuracy once all testing examples have been assigned a prediction.

Also, make sure that the model is not being updated in between testing batches.

Comment: Do you have any reference on this? Thank you.

Comment: Nope, just work out the arithmetic. Which statement are you unsure about?